# Has anyone successfully used the FuelSDK with Python 3?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

Devs have noted [issues when trying to use the FuelSDK with Python 3](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/issues) available in PyPI. One user mentions he works around this by developing against the code locally. How have others worked around this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good timing, the [version 1.0.0](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/tree/v1.0.0) was released 4 days back and seems to have resolved some of the issues you pointed out. You need to be using `Suds-jurko 0.6`

I can confirm most of the basic FuelSDK operations seem to be working okay with Python 3.x

Comment: Nice. I just installed with 
`pip install git+https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python.git@v1.0.0`

Comment: I installed it with the command above, but I don't see config.python.template

Comment: @wobbly_col config.python.template is as https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/FuelSDK/config.python.template